# XML samples of BACnet/WS, standard 135-2012?

Tags: bacnet

I have been reading about Bacnet/WS in ANSI/ASHRAE Standard 135-2012.

Does anyone have some XML samples of how the request and response should look like?
E.g how should the request for getValue look like and how should its response look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples in [Addendum 135-2012am](http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/Add-135-2012am-PPR1-draft-26_chair_approved.pdf) and much more specification of the general "BACnet/HTTP" stuff. Note that the addendum is currently a draft but I guess it will improve the ASHRAE Standard 135-2012 official soon.

See also the [1st Advisory](http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/Add-135-2010am-APR1-1_chair-approved.pdf) for more information.

Comment: I was actually thinking of the SOAP service that was introduced in 2004, but this new introduction looks a lot more sophisticated. Has this addendum been approved? Do you know anything about when it will be official?

Comment: Its available for public review which will end at 7th July. Have a look at http://www.bacnet.org/Addenda/ to be noticed for updates or join the working group [bacnet-dm](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!forum/bacnet-dm)